# I need an android emulator other than android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, virtual-machine, genymotion

android studio is too powerful for my machine.
genymotion won't work either I get this error "unable to start the virtual device"
any solution? i followed all the steps
can i use my phone instead of virtual device? and how?

Comment: Did you find: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use your android phone follow this link for detailed steps https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device